# ASP.NET: How can i update hidden field in JQuery or Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have a hidden field in my view.
I have list of strings that i would like to put as comma separated values in to hidden field.
I am trying to access the hidden field.
Is it possible? Any other best practice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried something like

```
$('input[name=hiddeninputname]').val(theValue);
```

Comment: +1 - another option might be the `#` syntax. `$('#hiddenFieldId').val(theValue);`.

Comment: Or if it is a `runat="server"` hiddenfield use `$('#' + '<%= hiddenFieldId.ClientID %>').val(theValue);`

Answer (score 0):

For asp.net `hiddenfield` use this:

```
$("[id$=idofthehiddenfield]").val(commaseperatedvalues);
```